# How do I target the child theme with get_bloginfo();?

Tags: php, child-theme

In the code below (which is located in my `functions.php` file), in reference to `('.get_bloginfo('template_url').'`, I'm trying to target my child theme but it keeps coming up as the parent theme.

```
/* ==  Custom Login Logo ==============================*/
function custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style>
        .login h1 a { background:url('.get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/logo-white.png) 0 0;background-size:218px 32px;height:32px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:20px;padding:0;width:218px }
    </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_logo');
```

How can I make it so it targets the child theme's theme folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) which

> Retrieves stylesheet directory URI for the current theme/**child** theme

```
/* ==  Custom Login Logo ==============================*/
function custom_login_logo() {
    echo '<style>
        .login h1 a { background:url('.get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/images/logo-white.png) 0 0;background-size:218px 32px;height:32px;margin-bottom:10px;margin-left:20px;padding:0;width:218px }
    </style>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'custom_login_logo');
```

*You might need to modify the path to your image slightly depending on it's place in your theme's folder structure*

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I'll give you the check in 6 min.